# InnoDB: "Only one log file found" after binary import

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, mysql-5.6, backup, xtrabackup

My first one on DBA...

After successful upgrading a master MySQL server 5.5 to 5.6.17 (CentOS 6 VPS serer), I done and moved my binary backups to a slave server (same version 5.6.17 but different environment on Jelastic). The binary backup was done using Percona Xtrabackup 2.1.7 with preparation. Both systems are x86_64 GNU/Linux

After restoring the binary backups to `/var/lib/mysql` and starting MySQL I was welcomed with the following error from MySQL log:

```
140725 15:02:11 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2014-07-25 15:02:13 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [ERROR] InnoDB: Only one log file found.
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [Note] Binlog end
2014-07-25 15:02:13 11854 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
```

This is `ls /var/lib/mysql`

```
backup-my.cnf
ibdata1
ib_logfile0
xtrabackup_binary
xtrabackup_binlog_info
xtrabackup_binlog_pos_innodb
xtrabackup_checkpoints
mysql
.... OTHER DATABASE FOLDERS .....
```

This is very strange, and it used to work perfectly fine when I was setting up 5.5 > 5.5 replication exactly the same was.

**Why is it failing with 5.6 now?**
**What does it mean: [ERROR] InnoDB: Only one log file found"**
Additionally on the master I can see `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` but Xtrabackup gives only `ib_logfile0`

- I tried restarting the server.
- I tried doing the backup/restore prcedure twice to make sure I didn't miss something.
- I tried removing ib_logfile0 file as suggested somewhere on the official MySQL forum.
- I tried explicitly enabling InnoDB in my.cnf with `Innodb=ON`

**EDIT: Answering for questions:**

The actual line I'm using for the backup?

```
ulimit -n 10240 && sudo -u mysql \
    /bin/sh -c "cd /var/lib/mysql && /usr/bin/innobackupex          \
      --user=${MYSQL_BACKUP_USER} --password=${MYSQL_BACKUP_PASS}   \
      --lock-wait-query-type=update --lock-wait-timeout=300         \
      --kill-long-query-type=select --kill-long-queries-timeout=10  \
      --rsync --slave-info --safe-slave-backup ${XB_TARGET_DIR}"
```

/usr/bin/innobackupex --version

```
InnoDB Backup Utility v1.5.1-xtrabackup;
```

cat xtrabackup_binary

```
xtrabackup_56
```

cat backup-my.cnf

```
# This MySQL options file was generated by innobackupex.

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
innodb_checksum_algorithm=innodb
innodb_log_checksum_algorithm=innodb
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_files_in_group=2
innodb_log_file_size=50331648
innodb_fast_checksum=0
innodb_page_size=16384
innodb_log_block_size=512
innodb_undo_tablespaces=0
```

Do you have the log files outside of the datadir?

```
No, log files are within the datadir
```

Comment: What is the actual line you are using for the backup? Is it using the right binary -_55 or _56 (are you using xtrabackup or innobackupex)? Has the `backup-my.cnf` have a innodb_log_files_in_group = 1? Do you have the log files outside of the datadir? All these are common mistakes.

Comment: Hi @jynus Just updated my question with some answers. Is it possible that it may be related to me not using xtrabackup to restore but extracting the backup on my own? I don't have it installed on slave and probably won't be able to since it's a Jelastic DBaS with very limited SSH access

Comment: So, the big question is: do yo run `innobackupex --apply-log` -that should run xtrabackup twice, the second run regenerates the (empty) logs. You can run that anywhere, but before starting your slave.

Comment: I do run ONCE: sudo -u mysql innobackupex --user=U --password=P --apply-log --use-memory 2G /path-to-backup
Again, used this many times and it's always worked for 5.5

Comment: That seems ok, provide log for that, as that is the step failing (or the copy after that).

Comment: That's getting closer. I was mistakenly suppressing errors and missed:
innobackupex: ibbackup failed at /usr/bin/innobackupex line 2580.
Failing code is: https://gist.github.com/WooDzu/e4f4a733d8aece74a180

Comment: Can you check if you also get OS error 2 before that? It is related to permissions/access problems/disk space. This is my best bet, error at OS level. BTW, user/password is not needed for the apply-log phase (can be done on a different server).

Comment: I run backup and prepare again. Here's full output from prepare: https://gist.github.com/WooDzu/2fc09f4d1fad1e05374f

Comment: Ok, bug in 2.1.7 fixed in 2.1.8 (and in 2.2.x): https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtrabackup/+bug/1273468 Now you own me a beer!

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it. Pls find me on LinkedIn so I don't forget about the beer for you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have run `innobackupex --apply-log` successfully you either have a configuration problem (probably `innodb_log_files_in_group` is 1 in the original and 2 -or not set- in the restored server) or you lost ib_logfile1 somewhere in the process.

InnoDB is ok, it is normal for it to fail when it detects a different configuration on disk than on the file.

Please be aware that xtrabackup/innobackupex only copies data files, not the `/etc/my.cnf`.

**Final answer**: apply-log wasn't being executed successfully- a mistake while logging was concealing that. The actual error was due to a [specific bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtrabackup/+bug/1273468) in an old version of Percona XtraBackup. Update to a newer version >= 2.1.8 should fix that.

Comment: Hi. Just checked innodb_log_files_in_group is set to 2 on both servers. I'm gonna change it to 1 on the slave and see how it goes

Comment: Don't do it. It is supposed to generate an exact copy, you may corrupt your backup. Check for my comment above for suggestions to check. Check both global status *and* my.cnf.

Comment: Restoring from version 2.1.9 was successful and MySQL starts fine now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Nice `Final Answer`. +1 !!!